# Azure web app deployment does not follow ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT configuration in selecting appsettings.json

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have appsettings.Production.json to define some settings overrides for the appsettings.json. This seems to work when testing locally and setting the launch settings to define ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.

After deployment with Azure DevOps pipeline and debloymen job the Web App does not work due to clearly using the default appsettings.json. Even setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to App Service configuration does not have any effect and the value should anyways default to Production.

On the deployed web app, Kudu shows all definitions of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to be set to Production as expected with App Settings as well as in environment variables.

Deployment job is defined as follows:

```
  - deployment: deployWebAPI
    displayName: 'Deploy WebApi'
    dependsOn: fanOut
    variables:
      environmentName: $[ stageDependencies.build.setParameters.outputs['setParametersStep.environmentName'] ]
      appServiceName: $[ stageDependencies.build.setParameters.outputs['setParametersStep.appServiceName'] ]
      resourceGroupName: $[ stageDependencies.build.setParameters.outputs['setParametersStep.resourceGroupName'] ]
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            displayName: 'Download webApp artifact'
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: $(webAppArtifactName)
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appName: $(appServiceName)
              deployToSlotOrASE: true
              resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroupName)
              package: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/$(webAppArtifactName)/MyWebApi.zip 
              deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
```

Answer (score 0):

The deployment job variable `environmentName` must be the significant part here. It was defined as follows in beginning of our pipeline definition yml:

```
variables:
  environmentName: 'test-dev'
```

This seems to generate a Web.Config with `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` defined as environment variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyWebApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Changing that variable to correct value `Production` fixed the issue.

Some debugging notes:

- Logging following variable on startup can be useful as you cannot rely even on Kudu:
  `hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName`
- Strangely this web.config is in place already in build artifacts on pipeline although local publish package creation with `dotnet publish --configuration Release` does not set the env variable.
- Direct publish from local env worked, so when in doubt diff your locally created publish package to the one deployed to the server by pipeline.